# Haskell: For Loops?

Tags: haskell

I am new to Haskell and looking to replicate the below in Haskell.  What is the best way of approaching For loops?

```
    kCenterX = kCols / 2;
    kCenterY = kRows / 2;

for(i=0; i < rows; ++i)              // rows
{
for(j=0; j < cols; ++j)          // columns
{
    for(m=0; m < kRows; ++m)     // kernel rows
    {
        mm = kRows - 1 - m;      // row index of flipped kernel

        for(n=0; n < kCols; ++n) // kernel columns
        {
            nn = kCols - 1 - n;  // column index of flipped kernel

            // index of input signal, used for checking boundary
            ii = i + (m - kCenterY);
            jj = j + (n - kCenterX);

            // ignore input samples which are out of bound
            if( ii >= 0 && ii < rows && jj >= 0 && jj < cols )
                out[i][j] += in[ii][jj] * kernel[mm][nn];
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Idiomatic Haskell would do this in a very different way.  I think you should study some basic concepts of functional programming in Haskell.  If you're not used to it, it will be very weird at first, but it's fun once you get into it, imo.  By restructuring the problem in a better way for FP, it may become immensely easier, in fact.  At first you might think you have to write your function recursively, and you *will* have to learn to do that, but if the problem fits, there may be higher-order functions that will make the problem almost trivial.  FP is not a new syntax for imperative concepts.

Comment: In general, you don't rewrite code in Haskell.  You just write code in Haskell, starting from a description of what the inputs and outputs are and how they're related, not starting from a description of how you would do something in a different language.

Comment: Since (at a glance) you are doing some rather tricky index stuff, you could port this in essentially imperative style using [`ST` arrays](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/array-0.5.2.0/docs/Data-Array-ST.html).  Otherwise you'll have to dig into *why* of the algorithm and phrase it a different way.

Comment: "Please translate this code for me" is a poor way to learn new idioms.  I suggest you try to learn Haskell and eagerly ask questions when something stumps you.  Asking a broad question without direction, as done here, isn't an efficient way to learn the language.

Comment: A library like `linear` could be helpful.

Answer (score 3):

Since (at a glance) you are doing some rather tricky index stuff, you could port this in essentially imperative style using [`ST` arrays](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/array-0.5.2.0/docs/Data-Array-ST.html).  Otherwise you'll have to dig into *why* of the algorithm and phrase it a different way.

Here's an example to get you going.  The following C code (which I chose because it has index math on the left side of the assignment)

```
void example(const int* input, int size, int* output) {
    // assume output initialized with zeros
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        int newi = i/2;
        output[newi] = input[i];
    }
}
```

can be translated *literally* into Haskell as:

```
import Control.Monad (forM_)
import Data.Array.ST
import Data.Array

example :: Array Int Int -> Array Int Int
example input = runSTArray $ do
    output <- newArray (bounds input) 0
    forM_ (indices input) $ \i -> do
        let newi = i `div` 2
        writeArray output newi (input ! i)
    return output
```

(Though that is miles away from how we would express that function in *idiomatic* Haskell.)

If you have specific questions about what's going on with this notation, how to expand to multidimensional arrays, how to work with a pure `Array` once you've got it, or anything else, I would suggest you ask it as a separate question.

I will also say that this task uses some of the more sophisticated Haskell concepts (mainly because we have to play some tricks to speak imperative in a functional language) and if you are brand new to Haskell, this might not be the best place to start.  Good luck!

Answer (score 3):

After looking at your code a while, it seems to be a code to apply a convolution kernel with 0 borders (truncated access). So my first step is a [stackage search for convolve](https://www.stackage.org/lts-11.9/hoogle?q=convolve). In practical terms, I'd then choose one that uses a suitable datatype such as the [Data.Array.Repa.Algorithms.Convolve](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-11.9/repa-algorithms-3.4.1.2/Data-Array-Repa-Algorithms-Convolve.html) version. In that case, I'd write your function as:

```
outarray = runIdentity $ convolveOutP (outAs 0) kernel inarray
```

Where `runIdentity` comes from Data.Functor.Identity and is used to unwrap the monad `convolveOutP` returns data within.

But implementing the function, rather than finding it, is another task entirely. I'd start with a suitable data type, for instance from [Data.Vector.Unboxed](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-11.9/vector-0.12.0.1/Data-Vector-Unboxed.html#t:Vector) (which is also used by Repa). Those don't have 2D indexing, but we could implement it using [Data.Ix](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.0.0/docs/Data-Ix.html). Or someone already did that for us in [Data.Array](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/array-0.5.2.0), so let's start out with that.

Firstly, our array indices now don't need to start from zero. So we can define a kernel with its center at zero:

```
import Data.Array.Unboxed

kernelShape = ((-1,-1), (1,1))
-- Simple blurring kernel function for example
weight (x,y) = 2**(-2-fromIntegral (abs x)-fromIntegral (abs y))
kernel :: UArray (Int,Int) Float
kernel = listArray kernelShape [weight (x,y) | (x,y) <- range kernelShape]
-- We can check the weights add up:
one = sum $ elems kernel
```

Incidentally, this means we can have a kernel that extends asymmetrically if we wish. Our output function is an array of sums, something that can be built with [accumArray](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/array-0.5.2.0/docs/Data-Array-IArray.html#v:accumArray). So we can now begin to formulate a convolution:

```
convolve kernel inA = accumArray (+) 0 (bounds inA) placedterms
  where placedterms = [((x,y), (kernel!(lx,ly)) * (inA!(x+lx,y+ly))) |
                       (x,y) <- indices inA, 
                       (lx,ly) <- indices kernel, 
                       inRange (bounds inA) ((x+lx),(y+ly))]

convolvedkernel = convolve kernel kernel :: UArray (Int,Int) Float
```

Note the `inRange` test to make sure our accesses are possible. This is naturally not a particularly efficient implementation, but seems to work.